Import config to a new C9200
The task is to replace a legacy C2960X-24PD-L with a new C9200-24P plus its network module C9200-NM-4G. I couldn't find a document on migrating these two models directly so I decided to configure the new switch from scratch.
I prefer using web interface but failed to connect the switch after completing
Classic Day 0 Wizard.
On page 14 of the document below, it's not very clear how to locate the Ethernet Interface Global Unique Identifier (GUID). So I added a DhcpClientIdentifier to each folder under Interfaces.
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9200/software/release/17-14/configuration_guide/b-1714-9200-cg.pdf
On page 15/16, it says I am supposed to get an IP address at 192.168.1.x/24 range but what I got was 169.254.1.x. I have set up my network adapter properly, but couldn't ping 192.168.1.1 or 169.254.1.1.
Then I have no choice but to use CLI. The serial connection works well.
I have a couple of questions.

C2960 is on version 15.0 while C9200 should be on a later version. Are they compatible? There are other 8x C2960 switches operating on this network, either on version 15.0 or 15.2.
Before swapping the new switch into the network, how to access its web interface via my laptop?
I watch this video and assign an IP address to its management port, but it doesn't work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b23fx7gjS54

It's my first time configuring a new switch and it's quite difficult. Thank you for any ideas.

To answer your first question, the versions are “compatible” in the sense that most of the configuration commands (but not all) can be copied from the 2960 to the 9200.  You may need to pay attention to the interface names.  On the 9200, they will be named GigabitEthernet 1/0/x, where x is 1 — the max number of ports.  It's been a long time since I configured a 2960, but they may be Gi 0/1 or something like that.
The network module will be Gigabit (or Tengigabit, depending on the module type) 1/1/x.
The operating system itself is not compatible with different models.

The layer-2 QoS is completely different between the two. I am working on replacing some 2960 switches with 9200 and 9300 switches.
